# Retrieve new and old path of a renamed file under observing directory

Tags: android, fileobserver

My App saves recorded video files in a specific folder in external directory and saves meta data including the path of every file in database . I need to Observe  remove , rename and move of my file in case of keeping database updated with new file path. I read  about `FileObserver` in android. If I give the path of my directory in SD Card for example `/storage/emulated/0/my_recordings` as input path of my `FileObserver`, events will be fired for all of my files in the input path and also it will be fired for `MOVED_TO` event type which i use to observe rename operation of files under my directory,  I will get the new relative `path` of my file in the path argument of `onEvent (int event, String path)`  but how can I retrieve the old file name or old file path of that file to understand which database entry I have to update ? I passed the path of parent directory of that file so I don't have the old file name.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There should be a `MOVED_FROM` event right before the `MOVE_TO`. The path of the `MOVED_FROM` event should be the old file name while the path in the `MOVED_TO` should contain the new file name. Make sure that you monitor this event type by explicitly passing it in the `flags` parameter of the `FileObserver` constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a MOVED_FROM event right before the MOVE_TO. The path of the MOVED_FROM event should be the old file name while the path in the MOVED_TO should contain the new file name.

Also make sure that you monitor this event type by explicitly passing it in the flags parameter of the FileObserver constructor.